# Inserting multiple tags to database in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, tags, jquery-tokeninput

I'm trying to insert multiple tags into database.
I'm using TokenInput plugin to gather users' tags.
I get a string of tags separated by comma, like this:

```
if($_POST) {
$data = $_POST['tags'];
$tags = explode(",", $data);
$snap = 6;
echo $data;
}
```

The data comes from an ajax function. When echoing $data I get a string like this:

Zara,Allsaints

Then I proceed to separate these by explode() and loop through the created array.

```
if($_POST) {
$data = $_POST['tags'];
$tags = explode(",", $data);
$snap = 6;

for($x = 0; $x < count($tags); $x++) {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO tags (tagid, tagname, snapid) VALUES ('', '$tags[x]', '$snap')");
  }
}
```

This code will insert empty values into 'tagname'. Have you got any suggestions what should I change to make this work? Should I rewrite the loop code?
Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Managed to do this. It was quite easy, should've given it more thought before posting.
So my code now is:

```
if($_POST) {
$data = $_POST['tags'];
$tags = explode(",", $data);
$snap = 6;

for($x = 0; $x < count($tags); $x++) {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO tags (tagid, tagname, snapid) VALUES ('', '" . $tags[$x] . "', '$snap')");
  }
}
```

With this I can insert as many tags as there are inside the array.
Hope somebody will find this useful one day.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use more optimal batch insert and also fix generating sql values string:

```
<?php

if($_POST) {
    $data = $_POST['tags'];
    $tags = explode(",", $data);
    $snap = 6;

    $values = array_map(function($item) use($snap) {
        return "('', '".$item."', '".$snap."')";
    }, $tags);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO tags (tagid, tagname, snapid) VALUES ".
        implode(",", $values);
    mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion. I don't really know how to use this array_map() function.
Also, about this one:
$sql = "INSERT INTO tags (tagid, tagname, snapid) VALUES ".
        implode(",", $values);
    mysql_query($sql);
This doesn't work and I get nothing back.

Comment: `array_map` return for each element of array modified value. In this case for each tag it return sql-string with values to insert. php array_* functions is more cool way to work with arrays:)